# Copying the text from the combo box instead of the primary key in my Access audit trail

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been working on this for a week and have not found a way still... within my access file, I have the following code that creates an audit trail for changes made to a form, would you be able to help me modify the code below so that when the change is made from a Combo box or a option group, the audit record shows the text value inside the combo box/option group instead of the primary key associated with that text value?

Thank you so much in advance.

K

```
Option Compare Database

Const cDQ As String = """"
Sub AuditTrail(frm As Form, recordid As Control)
  'Track changes to data.
  'recordid identifies the pk field's corresponding
  'control in frm, in order to id record.
  Dim ctl As Control
  Dim varBefore As Variant
  Dim varAfter As Variant
  Dim strControlName As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  'Get changed values.
  For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
    'Avoid labels and other controls with Value property.
    Select Case ctl.ControlType
    Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acListBox, acOptionGroup

      If IsNull(.Value) And Not IsNull(.OldValue) Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "Audit (EditDate, User, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

      ElseIf IsNull(.OldValue) And Not IsNull(.Value) Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "Audit (EditDate, User, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

      ElseIf .Value <> .OldValue Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "Audit (EditDate, User, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

      End If
    End Select
    End With
  Next
  Set ctl = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine _
   & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

Comment: Include the text field as column of combobox and reference that column by its index. Index begins with 0. `Me.combobox.Column(1)`. As for an OptionGroup (radio buttons?), that gets more complicated. Edit question to show data for OptionGroup.

Comment: Include the text field as column of combobox?

Comment: Combobox RowSource like `SELECT ID, fieldname FROM table;`. ColumnCount: 2; ColumnWidths: 0";2". The 0 width will hide column. This is basic functionality.

Comment: @June7, I'd add this as an answer.  If you can lay it out a bit more step-by-step it's a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For combobox, include text field as column of combobox and reference that column by its index. Combobox RowSource like `SELECT ID, fieldname FROM table;`. Set ColumnCount: 2; ColumnWidths: 0";2" (0 will hide column). Index begins with 0 so if text field is second column, its index is 1. `Me.combobox.Column(1)`.

Assuming option group uses radio buttons, each radio button has a numeric OptionValue. The option group frame adopts the selected radio button OptionValue as Value. Convert these numbers to associated descriptive text. Either do DLookup() to a table or hard-code conversion. Example with 3 radio buttons with OptionValue 1, 2, 3:
`Choose(Me.optGender, "Female", "Male", "Not Given")`